# esri Print dijit fails when using the Export service of my arcgis Server and works when the same is hosted in arcgis online

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, export, printing

I am using the print dijit so as to export a web map that contain a WebTiledLayer.
When I use as of the export servive one that directs to arcgis online it works properly.
On the other hand when I change the url, so as to point to my service, exporting fails, getting a timeout error which says : dojo.io.script error RequestTimeoutError: Timeout exceeded { message="Timeout exceeded"............

My server is arcgis 10.2.2 while the online one is 10.2.1, but I dont think this can be a problem 
     I

```
  <script>
  var app = {};
  app.map = null; app.toolbar = null; app.tool = null; app.symbols = null; app.printer = null;
  require([
  "esri/layers/WebTiledLayer",
    "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Print",
    "dojo/dom", "dijit/form/Button",
  ], function(

  WebTiledLayer,
    Map, Print,
     dom, 
     Button
  ) {
    app.map = new Map("map", {
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 3
    });
    // print dijit
    app.printer = new Print({
      map: app.map,
      url: "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task"
      //url: "http://myserver:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task"
    }, 
    dom.byId("printButton"));
    app.printer.startup();
    var tiles="http://www.mytiles.int/cpdbmap/graybasemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" ;
    var tiledLayer = new esri.layers.WebTiledLayer(tiles.replace('{z}/{x}/{y}','${level}/${col}/${row}'), {
                    id: "anID"
                });
     app.map.addLayer(tiledLayer);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the service 
http://myserver:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task

of the same execution type (esriExecutionTypeSynchronous) as the arcgisonline one?

Comment: Yes it is of the same type.

Comment: the next question then is whether or not the 'arcgis' user on the machine hosting ArcGIS Server is allowed to make internet requests to access the resources you'd like to print.

Comment: @JohnGravois If you mean if there is connectivity. Yes there is. From the machine hosting the gis server I can see the tiled map. Only the PrintTask service is not able to do it.

Comment: @JohnGravois Connectivity of the service to external resouses (in my case the tiled service) could be the problem. But how could I check if my arcgis user who owns the service (PrintTask) can see external resources ?

Comment: you should be able to sign into the machine with the 'arcgis' user credentials and test from a browser.

Comment: @Smalis did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing the same problem on a client's ArcGIS Server (so I don't have easy access to test the arcgis user as John described above)